# Can I omit Return value in arrow function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, arrow-functions

I've been struggled from this for a long time.  we all know that **arrow function** simplifies the syntax, like this:

A. Arrow function:

```
        onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
```

B. Expand the Arrow function:

```
        onClick={() => {
           // we can see there is a return keyword here. can I just remove the return keyword ? 
           return toggleTodo(todo.id); 
           ^^^^^^
        }}
```

In the official redux tutorial, the file `AddTodo.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {                   // focus on this line
          e.preventDefault()
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value)).  // focus on this line, if i put return here, the code below won't be executed. if not, how to explain the syntax in the beginning?
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input ref={node => (input = node)} />
        <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect()(AddTodo)
```

The question is: in the `onSubmit`, why we don't need to put a `return` inside the function body ? Thank you.

Comment: A and B are both arrow functions, what do you mean `B.Without arrow function`

Comment: An expression-bodied arrow function returns its expression, yes, but other types of functions don’t *need* to contain a `return`. Would you have the same question about `function (e) { /* no return */ }`, or is it just for arrow functions?

Comment: return is quite literally what it sounds like. It returns the value to the caller so the caller can do something with it. A function without a return statement will return a default value. In onSubmit, all of those functions are side-effects, they alter some state. We do not return side effects

Comment: Or is the question why someone would write `() => toggleTodo(todo.id)` if the return value isn’t important? (If so: it’s to make it short. I prefer writing `() => { toggleTodo(todo.id); }` explicitly, personally.)

Comment: @TríPhan my fault, i have corrected the question body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to `return` something if that returned value will be used somewhere. In the case of `onSubmit`, there is no need to `return` anything. That (arrow) function is simply running some code when the form is submitted.

In point **B** in your question, yes, you can remove `return` **if** nothing needs to be done with the returned result of `toggleTodo(todo.id)`.

Comment: From the official definition(Mozilla):
`(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }` , so the return is optional ?

Comment: When it's defined as `(...) => expression`, yes, the `return` is implied (the `expression` will always be returned).

Answer (score 1):

### They are both arrow functions

> `onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}`

Short version

> ```
>  onClick={() => {
>     toggleTodo(todo.id);
>  }}
> ```

Long version

> ```
>  onClick={() => {
>     toggleTodo(todo.id);
>     toggleTodo2(todo.id);
>     toggleTodo3(todo.id);
>  }}
> ```

Long version can have multiple calls, `return` not required

Comment: in the short version you provided, are you sure it can be simplified to the first arrow function

Comment: `(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }`. copied from the mozilla, you mean the `return` is optional?

Answer (score 1):

You need a return value when you use a synchronized function and need its result.

Whenever you use an asynchronous function, it means that the calling function already continued with itself and moving to the next phase will be via a callback function.

In your case the `window` object is the caller of the `onClick`, so there's no reason to return a value to it, it will have nothing to do with it.

You do want to trigger react's rendering mechanism so you use the dispatch callback/trigger.